# Exclude live events from YouTube data api search query

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I'm using the google-api-php-client (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to search and retrieve only videos from YouTube.  I know you can set a query marker called type to video like this:

```
$searchquery = array(
      'q' => "flux",
      'maxResults' => 10,
      'type' => 'video',
      'videoDuration' => 'short',
      'videoEmbeddable' => 'true'
    );
```

However it seems to also return live events/livestreams in the search results.  Is there a way to exclude live event videos?  They have a marker called `[liveBroadcastContent] => upcoming` so I can do post-search but that's not ideal.  Thanks in advance.

edit: on closer inspection, not all livestreams even seem to have the marker [liveBroadcastContent] set.  I have found some that are set to none as with ordinary videos.