# C# Youtube API: Exclude livestreams from search

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am making an application using the search feature from the YouTube Data API in C#, and am having trouble with limiting my search query to only videos (No live events).

Here is the code I have been using,

```
        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = Message;
        searchListRequest.Type = "video";
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 1;
        searchListRequest.SafeSearch = SearchResource.ListRequest.SafeSearchEnum.Strict;

        var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();
```

I have tried `searchListRequest.EventType = SearchResource.ListRequest.EventTypeEnum.Completed;`, but this only returns completed live events, which is not what I want.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) to know what query parameters are supported in searching using YouTube API.

`videoType` - The videoType parameter lets you restrict a search to a particular type of videos. If you specify a value for this parameter, you must also set the type parameter's value to video.

Acceptable values are:

- `any` – Return all videos.
- `episode` – Only retrieve episodes of shows.
- `movie` – Only retrieve movies.

`type` - The type parameter restricts a search query to only retrieve a particular type of resource.
The value is a comma-separated list of resource types. The default value is video,channel,playlist.

Acceptable values are:

- channel
- playlist
- video

Check this [sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads), it shows here how to retrieve a list of videos uploaded in a channel.

Check also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025288/exclude-live-events-from-youtube-data-api-search-query), specially the edit part of the question.