# Prevent live broadcast in search result using Youtube api v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am using YouTube API v3 to search for videos using `Type = "video"` with 
**snippet** result.

Is there a way to tell YouTube API to ignore **Live** or **Upcoming** or **Completed** broadcasts videos in the result? Just need regular video search.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the [`Search:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) to know the parameters that this query supports.

> `eventType` - The **`eventType`** parameter restricts a search to broadcast events. If you specify a value for this parameter, you must also set the [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) parameter's value to **`video`**.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - **completed** – Only include completed broadcasts.
> - **live** – Only include active broadcasts.
> - **upcoming** – Only include upcoming broadcasts.

Also from this post [Exclude live events from YouTube data api search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025288/exclude-live-events-from-youtube-data-api-search-query):

> on closer inspection, not all livestreams even seem to have the marker [liveBroadcastContent] set. I have found some that are set to none as with ordinary videos.

Comment: Thanks, When I **set** `eventType` it returns only event videos, while i need to ignore event videos (also updated question)